# Disable Drop-down list item without removing the value from FormCollection

Tags: javascript, c#, razor, asp.net-mvc-5

I have a number of the following drop-down lists within this page, each with a list of selectable users. When a user is selected in one list, I don't want them to be selected in any further lists. For this reason I have written a script to disable them.

When the form is submitted, the username of each user selected in a drop-down list should be appended to the `User`value in the Form Collection.

This works correctly without the disabling of names but when I add `seat-select`into the class description, the names are always returned in the FormCollection as empty strings.

Do you know why this is or what I can do to keep the names populating correctly in the FormCollection?

Drop-Down List:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.User, Model.UserList, "Select User", new { @class = "form-control seat-select", @id = "uniqueID", @onchange = "cleanUsers(this);" })
```

Java Script:

```
function cleanUsers(ddl) {
    var val = ddl.options[ddl.selectedIndex].value;
    var vOldVal =   $("#" + ddl.id).attr("data-selected");
                    $("#" + ddl.id).attr("data-selected", val);

    //Remove selected
    if (val != 0) { $(".seat-select option[value='" + val + "']").attr("disabled", true); }
    if (vOldVal != undefined) { $(".seat-select option[value='" + vOldVal + "']").attr("disabled", false); }
}
```

UPDATE 06/06/2016:
Apologies to bring back an old post. I have tried the advice listed below and this works to return one of the selected values. Unfortunately, In my solution I have a number of identical drop-down lists and I need to keep track of exactly which result is from which drop-down.

I have posted my new code below. The string is overwritten when each of the drop-down menus is changed so does not currently work for me.

New JavaScript:

```
function cleanRowers(ddl) {
     var val = ddl.options[ddl.selectedIndex].value;
     var vOldVal = $("#" + ddl.id).attr("data-selected");
     $("#" + ddl.id).attr("data-selected", val);

     //Remove selected
     if (val != 0) {
         $("#SelectedUserText").val(val);
         $(".seat-select option[value='" + val + "']").attr("disabled", true);
     }
     if (vOldVal != undefined) { $(".seat-select option[value='" + vOldVal + "']").attr("disabled", false); }
}
```

The Hidden value being updated:

```
@Html.HiddenFor(m => m.SelectedUserText)
```

I am trying to make the code as re-usable as possible so dont really want a different identifier for each of the drop-downs but it is important that I keep track of which drop-down the information is coming from.

Is there a way in which this can be done?

Answer (score 0):

Disabled attribute do not put value in form submission thats why you are receiving empty string .
Here is a trick you can apply :
Put the selected value in a hidden input field onchnage function then read the hidden value on form submission instead of reading vslue of disabled dropdown.
Hope that helps .

Comment: Thanks for the response, could you possibly post an example of how this would work?

Comment: Apologies for the late response. I managed to follow your advice, although as I have posted in my edit, this only allows me to store data for one of my drop-downs, do you know how I could get this to work for all of my duplicates?
Thanks

Comment: How about using the hidden input as array so  it holds multiple values ?
each time you select a dropdown value it gets pushed to hidden input but of course with a token to identify from input array later on server side.
Hidden input could be like below 
<input type="hidden" name="selectedUser[]" >